# how to fix an element inside bootstrap modal with respect to bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I want to fix an element inside bootstrap modal, but `position: fixed` but on scrolling it moves with the modal. I want it to stick at its place even after the modal is scrolled.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/898/). Here you will see the `Patate` text has `position: fixed` css attribute but if the modal is large then it moves with it. How can i fix this text to its place so that it stays at its position even if the modal is scrolled.

I had no luck with this. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can your text go inside the modal-title?

Comment: it will be in modal body

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might help. Using the grid inside the modal to separate the fixed div from the rest of your content.

```js
$('.launch-scroll').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#modal-scroll').modal({
    show: true
  });
});
```

```css
.modal {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.modal .modal-body {
    height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.modal .modal-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="container">
    <br />
    <button type="button" class="btn launch-scroll">Launch Confirm</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-scroll">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="modal-fixed">Patate</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-10">
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: i want to fix button in footer while scrolling content but how can we set dynamic height of the modal body. If there is scrollable content then fix the button in footer, if not scrollable content no need to fixed position. any suggestions.